# How can I safely cut small limestone bricks?

Tags: masonry, limestone

I have a number of long limestone bricks leftover after breaking down a large limestone planter. They're 2.5"x4", vary in length from 6" to 18", and some are mortared together. I'd like to cut them into 6" lengths and reuse them for a landscaping barrier. I already have a 10" jobsite table saw and a 7.25" worm drive circular saw.

Is my best bet to buy a segmented diamond blade for my circular saw and cut the bricks wet? Is it safe to use a 10" diamond blade on a table saw? (I haven't seen any mention of this online)

Comment: Do not wet cut with a saw not designed for wet cuts.  If you have to dry cut, wear a mask and use a vacuum to capture the dust stream.

Comment: Cutting masonry on a regular circular saw will also destroy the saw before long.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this https://www.harborfreight.com/4-12-in-turbo-wet-dry-masonry-diamond-blade-68878.html and good angle grinder, at least 7.00 amp and dig about 1/4” all 4 side and little tap with small hammer would do the job. You have to rest brick (one being cut) on two bricks on the edge.

Comment: Any reason to prefer the angle grinder over a circular saw? Easier to control?

Comment: Circular saw is okay. You can use it same way as circular saw, I mean scoring 1/4” all around and smacking with Mallet

Comment: @user1445709 the roughness of the stone/brick will quickly tear up the sole plate of your circular saw, so you'll be replacing the saw much sooner than you would probably want to.